# Contravariant functor Top -> Rings (Rotman *0.20)

Tags: category-theory

I'm just starting out with Rotman's intro AT book, and I find this exercise's second part slightly confusing:

''Show that $X \mapsto C(X) := \{\text{set of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$}\}$ gives a contravariant functor $\textbf{Top} \to \textbf{Rings}$.''

Since I'm very new to this topic, I'd like some help with concretely writing out this functor that must somehow map each continuous map $X \to Y$ to a ring homomorphism $C(Y) \to C(X)$. I'm sure this is very simple, I just haven't developed the intuition for it yet.

Comment: hint: the composition of two continuous functions is continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is meant is that the given definition is the object part of a contravariant functor. You are asked to figure out the definition on the morphisms.

Let's name the construction $C$, so $C(X)$ is given. Now, suppose $f\colon X\to Y$ is a given morphism. Then, define $C(f)\colon C(Y)\to C(X)$ by $C(\psi\colon Y\to \mathbb R)=\psi \circ f$. The rest of the exercise is verifying well-definedness and functoriality. These follow straightforwardly.

This is a special case of a representable functor: $C$ is the contravariant functor $\mathbf{Top}(-,\mathbb R)$, represented by the object $\mathbb R$. What's happening here is that the values of this representable functor don't just land in $\mathbf{Set}$, but in fact land in $\mathbf {Ring}$. So, more accurately, the functor $C\colon \mathbf{Top}\to \mathbf {Ring}$ has as underlying functor $\mathbf {Tpp}\to \mathbf{Set}$ the representable functor $\mathbf{Tpp}(-,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: This clarifies it nicely, thanks. I was a little confused by the new abstract notion. I'll have to get used to this kind of 'hierarchical' thinking.

Comment: You're welcome.